# Prepend lines to HTML file

Tags: linux, bash, html

i have following HTML file:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>Users</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>rundeck-read-only-iam-permissions</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>terraform_automated_python</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How to add following lines at beginning of file:

```
<br></br>
<caption><b>HTML E-mail</b></caption>
<br></br>
```

So final file should be:

```
<br></br>
    <caption><b>HTML E-mail</b></caption>
    <br></br>
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>Users</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>rundeck-read-only-iam-permissions</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>terraform_automated_python</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Choose the right tool first. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet).

Comment: For reference, see [Warning regarding “>”](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408#186126)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try,

```
echo -e "<br></br>\n\t<caption><b>HTML E-mail</b></caption>\n\t<br></br>\n$(cat FILENAME.html)" > FILENAME.html
```

I believe it will work fine. make sure to do backups of your files first just in case, but I think it will be fine, hope it helps

ALTERNATIVELY:

```
sed -i '1s/^/<br></br>\n\t<caption><b>HTML E-mail</b></caption>\n\t<br></br>\n/' FILENAME.html
```

Comment: Your second solution needs another `\n` at the end of the replacement string, and the two `\t` bytes change the indentation.

Comment: good call, I added the \n to the first, but not the second, and the \t while not necessary for html at all, does accurately reproduce the output requeted by OP. Thanks edited "sed" command now

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that the prepended text was not a literal copy.

Comment: (1) Your first answer (`echo`) fails if the html file contains any backslashes.  (2) Your second answer (`sed`) works only in GNU sed; it’s not POSIX-compliant.  … … … … … … … … … … … … …  See also [Warning regarding “>”](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408#186126).

Answer (score 1):

#### Say file `html1` has this content

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>Users</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>citrix-xendesktop-ec2-provisioning</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>rundeck-read-only-iam-permissions</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>terraform_automated_python</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### And file `html2` has this content

```
<br></br>
<caption><b>HTML E-mail</b></caption>
<br></br>
```

#### Merging the two using `cat`

- You just need to `cat (concatenate)` both files and redirect to third file say `html3`

  ```
  cat html2 html1 > html3
  ```

  What happens here is that both contents of `html2` and then `html1` are printed to STDOUT in the order passed and then finally content is redirected to file `html3` using redirection operator `>`.
- `NOTE` : Remember order in which you pass files is important that is to say that

  ```
  cat html2 html1 > html3
  ```

  `prepends html2 to html1`, but

  ```
  cat html1 html2 > html3
  ```

  `prepends html1 to html2` or saying other way `postpends html2 to html1`
- If you want, you can redirect it to `html1` only, making no need for `file3` like this

  ```
  cat html2 html1 > html1
  ```

Feel free to add in more details.

Comment: Yes, i know that way, just though is there any way from terminal, like sed command

Comment: In that case, see answer by @SeanDavey

Comment: @Milister: What are you talking about?  This answer is ‘‘from terminal’’, just as a `sed` solution is.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus: Your `cat html2 html1 > html1` command doesn’t work. In fact, it destroys `html1`. See [Warning regarding “>”](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408#186126).

Comment: @Scott, sed solution works perfectly for me

Comment: @Milister: Do you mean the sed solution in [Sean Davey’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1307217/150988#1307227)? (It’s clearer if you post comments under the thing they’re responding to.)  Naturally; you say you’re running Linux, and Linux includes GNU tools, including GNU sed.  Sean’s answer might not work on macOS, Solaris, BSD, and other non-Linux (non-GNU) systems.

Comment: Yes, and i already posted comment under his answer